# fluent-ffmpeg extract audio using streaming

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, streaming, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm trying to extract audio from video. This code works well:

```
ffmpeg('1.mp4').output('1.mp3')
.noVideo()
.format('mp3')
.outputOptions('-ab','192k')
.run();
```

But if I read the file with a stream like this:

```
var video = fs.createReadStream('1.mp4');
var audio = fs.createWriteStream('1.mp3');
ffmpeg(video).output(audio)
.noVideo()
.format('mp3')
.outputOptions('-ab','192k')
.run();
```

The output file weighs 1KB and does not have anything in it.

How can I extract audio using streams?

Comment: Is the Readstream seekable? If not, ffmpeg can't read the MP4.

Comment: What do you mean by "Readstream seekable"? The file is on the disk

Comment: FFmpeg needs to be able to go back and forth in the MP4. If the `fs` method doesn't support that, ffmpeg will not be able to parse the input.

Comment: Althoiugh you may be able to work around if your MP4 has MOOV box at the front..

Comment: @ABE, I had no problems running the code above. For my mp4 sample, I used the following file: https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement-files/blob/master/echo-hereweare.mp4 Can you verify this?

Comment: @r0hitsharma Yes, it works fine.
Why does it only work in your file?

Comment: @ABE, its hard to say, can you upload and link a file/sample which doesn't work in your case?

Comment: @r0hitsharma This sample file is causing problems.
https://dds.s3.nl-ams.scw.cloud/3.mp4
Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For further investigation, I added a callback for different sort of errors while transcoding, as well as other events. First hint was the following callback on `progress` event:

```
{ frames: NaN,
  currentFps: NaN,
  currentKbps: NaN,
  targetSize: 0,
  timemark: '00:00:00.00' }
```

As well, there was a `stderr` event:

```
ffmpeg version n4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20180831
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-shared --enable-version3
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x562c9e18de80] stream 0, offset 0x30: partial file
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x562c9e18de80] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 240x180, 374 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'pipe:0':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf54.63.104
  Duration: 00:00:14.72, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 240x180, 374 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25600 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 75 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x562c9e18de80] stream 1, offset 0xa1e: partial file
pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input
Output #0, mp3, to 'pipe:1':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    TSSE            : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libmp3lame
size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
{ frames: NaN,
  currentFps: NaN,
  currentKbps: NaN,
  targetSize: 0,
  timemark: '00:00:00.00' }
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
```

The latter explains the empty file you're seeing in the output. As to why the error only happens while streaming the file, and not while opening it through another method, this answer explains the details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40028894/1494833

Unfortunately the library doesn't yet support `movflags` input option as recommended above (https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/823).

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg doesn't like using using streams as inputs in my experience.  the following code worked for me, first let ffmpeg do its thing, then create/play with streams for the input/output:

```
         let video = `${files[0].filename}`;
         readstream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./${video}`))
           .on('error', () => {
             console.log("Some error occurred in download:" + error);
             res.send(error);
           })
           .on('finish', () => {
             let audio = `${video.split(".")[0]}.mp3`
             ffmpeg(`${video}`).output(audio)
               .noVideo()
               .format(`mp3`)
               .on(`end`, (stdout, stderr) => {
               let newReadstream = fs.createReadStream(`${audio}`);

               })
               .run()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you are using the [ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg) package which is basically a wrapper for running ffmpeg in node, you would have to do it somewhat like this:

This code works on my system using the same file you provided in the comments above but you may have to make some changes (Node v8.12.0, ffmpeg v0.0.4).

```
const ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg');

try {
    let process = new ffmpeg('3.mp4');
    process.then(function (video) {
        // Callback mode
        video.fnExtractSoundToMP3('3.mp3', function (error, file) {
            if (!error)
                console.log('Audio file: ' + file);
        });
    }, function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.code);
    console.log(e.msg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I probably did not understand, there's no problem extracting the audio, the problem is to use streams, your code will not work if you write this way: 

let process = new ffmpeg(fs.createReadStream('3.mp4'));

video.fnExtractSoundToMP3(fs.createWriteStream('3.mp3')