# ffmpeg not working with piping to stdin

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg, pipe, video-conversion

I want to stream a file that is being uploaded to ffmpeg. I'm using node.js and it's not working!

I ended up testing piping an input to ffmpeg from a local file, and this doens't work either. Here's my code:

```js
var processVideo = function(videoStream, resultPath) {
  var cmdParams = [
    '-i', '-',
    '-y',
    '-f', 'mp4',
    '-vcodec', 'libx264',
    '-vf', 'scale=-1:720',
    '-f', 'mp4',
    resultPath
  ];
  var ffmpeg = child_process.spawn('ffmpeg', cmdParams);

  var data = '';
  ffmpeg.stdout
    .on('data', function(chunk) { data += chunk; })
    .on('end', function() { console.log('result', data); });

  var err = '';
  ffmpeg.stderr
    .on('data', function(chunk) { err += chunk; })
    .on('end', function() { console.log('error', err);});
  videoStream.pipe(ffmpeg.stdin);
};

processVideo(fs.createReadStream(pathToLocalMP4File), localPathToResultFile);
```

The output I get is

```
error ffmpeg version 2.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-libtheora --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fd1e2802a00] stream 0, offset 0x20: partial file
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fd1e2802a00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1920x1080, 16242 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 537134592
    compatible_brands: mp42    
    creation_time   : 2015-12-26 12:47:49
  Duration: 00:00:04.00, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1920x1080, 16242 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 60k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-12-26 12:47:49
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 32000 Hz, mono, fltp, 46 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-12-26 12:47:49
[buffer @ 0x7fd1e1c08e20] Unable to parse option value "-1" as pixel format
    Last message repeated 1 times
[buffer @ 0x7fd1e1c08e20] Error setting option pix_fmt to value -1.
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x7fd1e1c08f60] Error applying options to the filter.
Error opening filters!

result
```

I tried to set the `-pix_fmt` option, or `-analyzeduration` and `-probesize` as suggested by the error code and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659267/ffmpeg-10-04-could-not-find-codec-parameters) question, to no avail.

However `ffmpeg -i pathToLocalMP4File -y -f mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -vf scale=-1:720 -f mp4 localPathToResultFile` works perfectly in the terminal...

Any idea??