# What is causing "unspecified pixel format" and "Error opening filters!" error in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, http-live-streaming

I'm writing an mp4 to HLS transcoding process that works as intended on files smaller than 7 gigabytes (sample size is 100 videos). When attempting to transcode anything larger than 7GB, it crashes.

The command:

```
ffmpeg 
  -i large_file.mp4 -y 
  -vf scale=w=1920:h=1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease 
  -c:a aac 
  -ar 48000 
  -c:v h264 
  -profile:v main 
  -crf 20 
  -sc_threshold 0 
  -g 48 
  -keyint_min 48 
  -hls_time 4 
  -hls_playlist_type vod 
  -b:v 5000k 
  -maxrate 5350k 
  -bufsize 7500k 
  -b:a 192k 
  -hls_segment_filename /1080p_%03d.ts 
  -threads 0 
  /tmp/output-ef42dc65-1d3d-4682-b32b-68d7c712fb9c-raw-test/1080p.m3u8
```

The error:

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.12-1\x7edeb9u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb9u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x555888d821c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1280x720, 3856 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'large_file.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.26.101
  Duration: 05:56:12.51, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4061 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1280x720, 3856 kb/s, 29.99 fps, 30 tbr, 100k tbn, 200k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 194 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[buffer @ 0x555888d88180] Unable to parse option value "-1" as pixel format
    Last message repeated 1 times
[buffer @ 0x555888d88180] Error setting option pix_fmt to value -1.
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x555888d81e40] Error applying options to the filter.
Error opening filters!
```

The error says to try increasing `analyzeduration` and `probesize`, which I set to max value (based on an answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11659459/3635086) post), however that didn't seem to change the behavior. I also suspected that the file was corrupted, but the fact that this is failing for all files larger than 7GB makes it more difficult to suggest its something not related to the size of the mp4.

Comment: Upgrade ffmpeg to 4.1 or newer (git) and check.

Answer (score 0):

The [comment by Gyan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54731858/what-is-causing-unspecified-pixel-format-and-error-opening-filters-error-in#comment96246706_54731858) turned out to be correct. We're using docker for our deployment (the transcoder is node.js leveraging fluent-ffmpeg), so upgrading wasn't as straightforward as you'd think as we needed multiple builds in the same image (aka a multi-stage build).

Issues we ran into:

- The [ffmpeg image by jrottenberg](https://hub.docker.com/r/jrottenberg/ffmpeg/) kept producing `error while
  loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object
  file: No such file or director`. There's an [issue](https://github.com/jrottenberg/ffmpeg/issues/143) open, though
  no solution has been offered, nor could I find one on my own.
- We found an [ffmpeg 4.1 image by alfg](https://hub.docker.com/r/alfg/ffmpeg/), however the
  executable is placed in `opt/ffmpeg/bin` instead of where we expected
  it to be, `/usr/local/bin`.

Given that, here's what our Dockerfile looks like. Worker is purring away at large files.

```
FROM alfg/ffmpeg AS ffmpeg # stored at /opt/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg
FROM node:10.10.0-alpine AS build
RUN npm install --global yarn@1.10.1
WORKDIR /app
# need these for native libraries like bcrypt
RUN apk update && apk add python g++ make && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
COPY . ./
RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile

FROM node:10.10.0-alpine
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/libgcc* /usr/lib/libstdc* /usr/lib/
COPY --from=ffmpeg / /
COPY --from=build /app /

# add ffmpeg's location to path
ENV PATH="/opt/ffmpeg/bin/:${PATH}"

CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```